# How to print a filled rectangle in Scala?

Tags: scala

Print a filled rectangle, where the filling is 
// the specified number of columns and rows of the character inChar,
// surrounded by a border made of the character edgeChar.

I'm confused so I understand I want to make multiple loops.
I have so far a nested loop where the outer loop is the number of columns and the inner loop is the number of rows. 
I'm confused how to print a specific number of dashes and +s 
and my loop content. 
and how and where does width and height come into play

```
for (k=1; k <= columns;  columns >= k++) {
  for (i = 1; i <= rows >= i++) {
    println(edgeChar)
    //println(+-)
  }

  for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++){
    for (j)
      println(edgeChar)
    }
    for (j = 1; j <= columns; j++){
      println(inChar)
    }
    for (k, k<=columns+2;k++){
      println(edgeChar)
```

Answer (score 4):

This being Scala, you probably want to map and play with lists rather than loops. Here's a working example (paste in the scala REPL):

```
val ec="@"
val cc="X"
val cols=8
val rows=5

((ec*(cols+2)) +: Range(0,rows).map( _ => ec+cc*cols+ec) :+ (ec*(cols+2)) ).mkString("\n")
```

This results in:

```
res22: String =
@@@@@@@@@@
@XXXXXXXX@
@XXXXXXXX@
@XXXXXXXX@
@XXXXXXXX@
@XXXXXXXX@
@@@@@@@@@@
```

Comment: FYI `Range(0, n)` can also be written `(0 until n)`

Comment: Major bonus points for the code in your answer also being precisely box-shaped. That is class.

Comment: A bonus point from a ScalaWag! I can happily die now :-)
Also, it's an interesting challenge to make such a rectangle using a shorter snippet (http://www.mbarsinai.com/blog/2015/04/01/print-a-filled-rectangle-in-scala/)